# ¿Es correcto implementar dos o mas interfaces en una misma clase en POO?

Tags: java, poo, clase, interface

Actualmente quiero iniciar un proyecto que va a escalar en un futuro en una medida que desconozco, así que me gustaría saber si esta forma es la correcta de aplicar interfaces en las clases

Forma (Por método):

Generar una interface por cada método estándar que se realice como por ejemplo (Listados, CRUDS repetitivos, Busquedas etc.).

```
 VerListado - interfaceListado
CRUD - interfaceCRUD
Busqueda - interfaceBusqueda
```

La forma de implementar las interfaces por medio de esta forma seria de la siguiente manera:

```
public class Prueba implements interfaceBusqueda, interfaceCRUD  {

}
```

Comment: Hola David. Creo que esta pregunta está basada en opiniones.. Si pudieras proveer de una manera objetiva de valorar  ambas opciones podria salvarse con reformulación. Si no, va a ser un debate/discusión de usuarios  con su opinión de *cuál es mejor* y por tanto cerrada. Un saludo

Comment: Como dice lois6b, preguntar de forma general cómo afrontar un proyecto desde el diseño es muy general y basado en opiniones. ¿Por qué no te pones con ello, y cuando tengas un caso concreto formulas una pregunta?

Comment: @lois6b ya modifique la pregunta, espero que ahora si este correcta su formulación, saludos

Comment: Una respuesta corta y anti-polémica: No es correcto, pero tampoco es incorrecto, si esa es la solución que necesitas, entonces aplicala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es totalmente correcto asociar a una clase una o muchas interfaces. Dependiendo de lo diseñado. Cabe recalcar que las interfaces son para definir familias de comportamientos comunes, por lo que, si tienes más de una clase con ese mismo conjunto de comportamientos es lógico que las utilices.

Te aconsejo no mirar hacia adelante y si preocuparte que las clases que hagas hoy en día tengas bases sólidas respecto a que sean de carácter particular (no tengan muchas responsabilidades), y que tengan sus comportamientos bien definidos. También si haces test unitarios mucho mejor.

Esto es importante para que, cuando la necesidad de extender el sistema llegue, puedas hacerlo con el menor impacto posible. No sobrediseñes tu solución, haz el mínimo código posible para atender los requerimientos, y hazlo de la mejor forma que te sea posible.

Saludos y suerte